# verilog compiler syntax error unexpected end

Tags: verilog

I am writing a test bench for AND module but it gives me the following error `near "end": syntax error, unexpected end.`

here is my code:

```
module TestAND();

reg A;
reg B;
wire C;

AND inst(A,B,C);


initial begin
 A=1;
 B=0;
 #100
end
```

Comment: do `#100;`, instead of `#100`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `;`after `#100` and you also missing `endmodule` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things here, you have an incorrect data type: `reg` is only used in an `always` block, and so here everything should be type `wire`.   Also if I recall correctly the primitives usually have the output first, so you would probably want `AND my_and (c,a,b);`

However, usually you don't use primitives directly unless you're creating libraries, and would want to use `assign c = a & b;` instead.

Comment: A `reg` can be assigned in an `always` or `initial` block. A `wire` can be assigned by an `assign` statement or module/primitive instantiation. Verilog primitives have lower-case names, `AND` could a user defined module not being shown.